# Tool to manipulate text in web form fields?

Tags: windows, browser, browser-addons, regex, string-manipulation

I'm looking for a way to manipulate text in form fields.  For example, if I have a large textarea "body" field, from my browser I want to be able to highlight a piece of text in that textarea, for example:

`www.example.com`

And hit a shortcut key to transform it into:

`<a href="www.example.com" rel="nofollow">www.example.com</a>`

I'm thinking maybe a regex replacer or macro.  Is there some kind of free broswer plugin (ideally for firefox) that would allow me to do this?

Comment: This can be done easily with AutoHotkey or similar macro software. Which OS are you using?

Comment: sorry windows 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I was able to do this with AutoHotKeys as suggested by iglvzx. I used the [AutoHotkey_L](http://l.autohotkey.net/) version

Here is my auto hot key script:

```
#space::
Send ^c<a href="^v" rel="nofollow">^v</a>
return
```

To use, I highlight the url I want:

`www.example.com`

And press Windows-key and spacebar. It gets transformed to:

`<a href="www.example.com" rel="nofollow">www.example.com</a>`